# Running grpc and http servers simultaneously

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I'm migrating an existing http application to a GRPC based application. For some time, both grpc and http will be running on different ports in the same go file, and I'll be moving the existing the http server part into a goroutine. This is how it would look like.

```
    main() {
        //Move existing server  into a goroutine
        go func() {
             s.server, err = chttp.NewHTTPSServer("443", s.certPath, s.keyPath, s.Router, s.options)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("server: error creating HTTP server - %v\n", err)
            }

            if err := s.server.Serve(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
                log.Fatalf("server: run error - %v\n", err)
            }
        }

        // Add new grpc server
        lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8433")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
        }
        a := grpc.NewServer()
        pb.RegisterNewServer(a, &test.GrpcServer{})
        if err := a.Serve(lis); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
        }

    }
```

Could this cause any issues, can grpc, http server be run simultaneously from the same program? I'm not sure if it could cause some issues I'm not aware of.

Comment: Running two servers in the same binary is just fine. Make sure if one dies the other should die as well. log.Fatal should take care of that.

Comment: I didn't do this. But the ex-owner of the service I'm currently maintaining exactly did this. Didn't face any issue related to this yet and it's been one and a half year. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is totally ok to run gRPC and HTTP servers from the same binary, as long as the ports are different.

But of course, if these two servers are doing different things, better to separate it.

And in case you wanted to do the same thing for both servers, using https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway is a common practice. It reads your protobuf definitions and generates a reverse-proxy server to translate an HTTP API into gRPC.

Comment: Well, always wanted to ask: REST is noun-centric and RPC is verb-centric, it looks like an absurd that people have to translate one to another, isn't? Do you know a serious company that uses grpc gateway in production?

Comment: I don't think it's absurd. Even when you create only REST API in your system, you will need to map it to a function which is a verb, right?
Several teams in my current company (https://www.deliveryhero.com/brands) are using grpc gateway. I also use it in my previous company where my API needs to be consumed by another backend over gRPC and a web frontend over REST.